# How to build new JSON with JSON_VALUE in SQL Server? Can't set value type

Tags: json, sql-server, json-value, azure-sql-edge

I have JSON like this:

```
{
  "_key": {
    "id": "3b8d1ed7-c3ec-32ec-a083-2ddc17152e94",
    "rootId": "15c85327-9628-3685-b84a-375b546ba92a",
  },
  "employeeInfo": {
    "idNumber": "3",
    "gender": "Male",
    "age": 20,
    ....
  },
  "product": {
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "_type": "Product",
    ...
  }
}
```

And I want to receive new JSON with desired fields. I'm using next query:

```
SELECT 
    '{ "employeeInfo": {"age: ' + 
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.employeeInfo.age') + ', "gender": ' + 
    JSON_VALUE(info, '$.employeeInfo.gender') + ' }' AS info
FROM 
    item.[Item] AS c
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT "rootId", MAX("revisionNo") AS maxRevisionNo 
     FROM item."Item"
     WHERE "rootId" = 'E3B455EF-D48E-338C-B6D4-FFD8B41243F9' 
     GROUP BY "rootId") AS subquery ON c."rootId" = subquery."rootId";
```

And I get this response:

```
{ "employeeInfo": {"age: 38, "gender": Female }
```

But it seems `JSON_VALUE` doesn't return type, so Female is without quotes. I don't know what fields will be requested, so I can't add quotes myself. How can I execute a query to return values with their types. I.e. I expect next response:

```
{ "employeeInfo": {"age: 38, "gender": "Female" }
```

I'm using this SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft Azure SQL Edge Developer (RTM) - 15.0.2000.1552 (ARM64)
```

UPD: I'm already have solution for postgres:

```
SELECT jsonb_strip_nulls(json_build_object('employee_info', json_build_object('age', c."info"->'employeeInfo' -> 'age', 'gender', c."info"->'employeeInfo' -> 'gender'), 'product', c."info"->'product')::jsonb) as info ...
```

And also need to build a request for sql-server. I will build this request dynamically when receive field names.

UPD2: I've created one more question which contains additional requirements. I need "product.plan" field also and have possibility to add any other fields [How to build JSON with selected fields from JSON columns in SQL server keeping fields type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024017/how-to-build-json-with-selected-fields-from-json-columns-in-sql-server-keeping-f)

Comment: Build the JSON with `FOR JSON`, not with string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly better syntax for @zhorov's excellent answer.

- Use a `ROOT` parameter instead of adding it to the column name.
- Put `$.employeeInfo` directly into `OPENJSON`
- Use a window function instead of a self-join

```sql
SELECT 
   info = (
      SELECT
        j.age,
        j.gender
      FROM OPENJSON(i.info, '$.employeeInfo')
        WITH (
          age sql_variant,
          gender varchar(10)
        ) j
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, ROOT('employeeInfo') 
   )
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.rootId ORDER BY i.revisionNo DESC)
    FROM item.Item AS i
    WHERE i.rootId = 'E3B455EF-D48E-338C-B6D4-FFD8B41243F9' 
) i
WHERE i.rn = 1;
```

If you want to do it completely dynamically then you need `OPENJSON` without a schema. Then rebuild it using a combination of `STRING_AGG` `CONCAT` and `STRING_ESCAPE`.

```sql
SELECT
  info = (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(
        '{"employeeInfo":{',
        STRING_AGG(
          CONCAT(
            '"',
            STRING_ESCAPE(j.[key], 'json'),
            '":',
            IIF(j.type = 1, CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(j.value, 'json'), '"'), j.value)
          ),
          ','
        ),
        '}}'
      )
    FROM OPENJSON(i.info, '$.employeeInfo') j
    WHERE j.[key] IN ('age', 'gender')
  )
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.rootId ORDER BY i.revisionNo DESC)
    FROM item.Item AS i
    WHERE i.rootId = 'E3B455EF-D48E-338C-B6D4-FFD8B41243F9' 
) i
WHERE i.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it hasn't resolved my issue. I receive fields in the request and dynamically generate database queries on the fly. I don't know the field types; I only have access to their names.

Comment: OK see new edit

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can I use it to get not only employeeInfo, but some additional fields, "product.plan" for example?. I don't see how I can add it to the FROM .. WHERE

Comment: It would help if you showed that in your question in the first place. I suggest you create a *new* question showing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024017/how-to-build-json-with-selected-fields-from-json-columns-in-sql-server-keeping-f

Comment: The solution is easy. To add another field it is required to add another SELECT CONCAT(... after 'info = (...)', like 'info = (SELECT CONCAT {"employeeInfo"....) + ', ' +  (SELECT CONCAT {"product"....)'

Comment: Possibly, although it may be more efficient to use another method. For example, you could just do `FOR JSON PATH` on such a subquery. Without a full example it's hard to say

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024017/how-to-build-json-with-selected-fields-from-json-columns-in-sql-server-keeping-f

Answer (score 1):

You may try to build the expected JSON with `FOR JSON PATH` and dot-separated column names for nested content, not with string concatenation. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-converts-sql-server-data-types-to-json-data-types-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) explains how `FOR JSON` converts SQL Server data types to JSON data types:

- SQL Server character and string types (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) are converted to string JSON string data type.
- SQL Server numeric types (int, bigint, float, decimal, numeric) are converted to JSON number data type.

Note, that with the additional `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` modifier, you may include the possible `NULL` values in the generated JSON.

```
SELECT 
   info = (
      SELECT 
         JSON_VALUE(info, '$.employeeInfo.age') AS "employeeInfo.age",
         JSON_VALUE(info, '$.employeeInfo.gender') AS "employeeInfo.gender"
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
   )
FROM ...
```

`JSON_VALUE()` always returns `nvarchar(4000)` and `FOR JSON` converts the values as JSON strings. If you need the actual data types, a solution is an explicit convertion with `CONVERT()` or an `OPENJSON()` call with explicit schema with actual columns data types.

```
SELECT 
   info = (
      SELECT age AS "employeeInfo.age", gender AS "employeeInfo.gender"
      FROM OPENJSON (info) WITH (
         age int '$.employeeInfo.age',
         gender varchar(10) '$.employeeInfo.gender'
      )
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
   )
FROM ...
```

SQL Server and Azure have limited JSON capabilities. If you do not know the actual data types of the referenced JSON properties, you need to call `OPENJSON()` with default schema and analyze the result (a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`). A possible approach, parsing only the `$.employeeInfo` part of the stored JSON, is the following statement:

```
SELECT 
   info = (
      SELECT CONCAT('{"employeeInfo": {', STRING_AGG(t.Pair, ',') ,'}}') 
      FROM (
         SELECT 
            CONCAT(
               '"', [key], '":', 
               CASE 
                  WHEN [type] = 0 THEN 'null' 
                  WHEN [type] = 1 THEN CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json'), '"') 
                  WHEN [type] = 2 THEN [value] 
                  WHEN [type] = 3 THEN [value] 
                  WHEN [type] = 4 THEN JSON_QUERY([value]) 
                  WHEN [type] = 5 THEN JSON_QUERY([value]) 
               END
            ) AS Pair 
         FROM OPENJSON (info, '$.employeeInfo')
         WHERE [key] IN ('age', 'gender') 
      ) t
   )
FROM ...
```

Comment: In this case, quotes are present in all values: '{"employeeInfo":{"age":"38","gender":"Female"}}' I don't need it for numbers

Comment: @ValeriyK., `JSON_VALUE()` always returns `nvarchar(4000)`. A solution is an explicit convertion with `CONVERT()` or an `OPENJSON()` call with explicit schema with actual column data types.

Comment: Or using normal column names, and `, ROOT('employeeInfo')`. Also use `'$.employeeInfo` in the `OPENJSON` call directly, rather than on each property.

Comment: @Charlieface, I agree. `OPENJSON(info, '$.employeeInfo')` is probably better in this specific situation. I included the full path syntax if the OP wants to access the values from different key (`product` for example).

Comment: It's not solve my issue. I receive fields in request and build requests to db on the fly - I don't know field types - only names

Comment: It seems he wants some dynamic solution that fetches fields from database and correctly types them? A bit like graphql

Comment: Yes, I want some dynamic solution. I already implemented it for postgres (see update) - I don't need to know field types for it