# How to build JSON with selected fields from JSON columns in SQL Server keeping fields type

Tags: json, sql-server, json-value, azure-sql-edge

I have JSON like this:

```
    {
  "_key": {
    "id": "3b8d1ed7-c3ec-32ec-a083-2ddc17152e94",
    "rootId": "15c85327-9628-3685-b84a-375b546ba92a"
  },
  "employeeInfo": {
    "idNumber": "3",
    "gender": "Male",
    "active": true,
    "age": 20
  },
  "product": {
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }
}
```

And I want to receive new JSON with desired fields. For some fields, I want to filter some inner fields (employeeInfo) and for some fields, I need to get all object. I'm using the next query:

```
SELECT
    '{ "employeeInfo": {"age: ' +
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.age') + ', "active": ' +
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.active') + ', "gender": ' +
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.gender') + ' }, ' +
    '"product":' + JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.product') + '}' as info
FROM 
    item.[Item] AS c
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT "rootId", MAX("revisionNo") AS maxRevisionNo 
     FROM item."Item"
     WHERE "rootId" = 'E3B455EF-D48E-338C-B6D4-FFD8B41243F9' 
     GROUP BY "rootId") AS subquery ON c."rootId" = subquery."rootId";
```

And I get response with such columns:

```
    { "employeeInfo": {"age: 20, "active": true, "gender": Male }, "product":{
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }}
```

But it seems JSON_VALUE doesn't return type, so 'Female' and 'Plan 1' are without quotes. I don't know what fields will be requested, so I can't add quotes myself. I will receive field names in runtime and want to build request dynamically. How can I execute a query to return values with their types? I.e. I expect the next response:

```
    { "employeeInfo": {"age: 20, "active": true, "gender": "Male" }, "product":{
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }}
```

I already have the solution for Postgres:

```
SELECT jsonb_strip_nulls(json_build_object('employee_info', json_build_object('age', c."info"->'employeeInfo' -> 'age', 'gender', c."info"->'employeeInfo' -> 'gender'), 'product', json_build_object('plan', c."info"->'product' -> 'plan'))::jsonb) as info ...
```

And also need to build a request for sql-server. I will build this request dynamically when I receive field names.

I'm using this SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft Azure SQL Edge Developer (RTM) - 15.0.2000.1552 (ARM64)
```

UPD: I'm using next query for testing:

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
  "_key": {
    "id": "3b8d1ed7-c3ec-32ec-a083-2ddc17152e94",
    "rootId": "15c85327-9628-3685-b84a-375b546ba92a"
  },
  "employeeInfo": {
    "idNumber": "3",
    "gender": "Male",
    "active": true,
    "age": 20
  },
  "product": {
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }
}'

SELECT
        '{ "employeeInfo": {"age: ' +
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.age') + ', "active": ' +
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.active') + ', "gender": ' +
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.gender') + ' }, ' +
        '"product":' + JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.product') + '}' as info
```

Actual result:

```
{ "employeeInfo": {"age: 20, "active": true, "gender": Male }, "product":{
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }}
```

Expected result:

```
{ "employeeInfo": {"age: 20, "active": true, "gender": "Male" }, "product":{
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "Product"
  }}
```

Comment: `{ "employeeInfo": {"age: 38, "gender": Female }, "product": {"plan": Plan 1} }` isn't valid JSON - are you sure that's what you get?

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to hand-construct JSON when SQL Server has built-in functions to extract and create JSON data. Have you tried reading the SQL Server documentation for [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server), [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql), [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) and [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) yet?

Comment: Yes, @Paul Maxwell, that's the answer I'm getting right now. That's why I'm asking how to get valid JSON.

Comment: Can you be more precise here please. A valid example JSON (without ... in it) and *exactly* which fields you require and which not.

Comment: See update in the question

Comment: Does this have to be done dynamically, or do you know the data types up front?

Comment: Yes, I will build sql dynamically. Currently, I do it as in my solution in current question. I will receive only field and inner fields names, like - `employeeInfo.age,employeeInfo.gender,product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR JSON PATH` to rebuild the JSON.

From your previous question, it appears you don't know the data types, so you can modify [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77023055/14868997) to include rebuilding `employeeInfo`. You need to use `JSON_QUERY` on it, otherwise you get double escaping.

`$.product` can be passed straight through without modification.

```
SELECT
  employeeInfo = JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT
      '{' +
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
          '"',
          STRING_ESCAPE(j.[key], 'json'),
          '":',
          IIF(j.type = 1, CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(j.value, 'json'), '"'), j.value)
        ),
        ','
      ) + '}'
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.employeeInfo') j
    WHERE j.[key] IN ('age', 'gender', 'active')
  )),
  product = JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.product')
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/VdnrmR3T)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the returned value is a numeric or not :

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.gender')) = 1
            THEN JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.gender')
            ELSE QUOTENAME(JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.employeeInfo.gender'), '"')
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` has major issues, `TRY_CAST` might be a better idea. But `OPENJSON` gives all the info you need anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say - I have to process boolean types also, all existing types.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solution, but maybe it can be improved? :

```
SELECT info = '{ ' +
                (SELECT CONCAT('"employeeInfo":{',
                               STRING_AGG(
                                       CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(j.[key], 'json'), '":',
                                              IIF(j.type = 1, CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE(j.value, 'json'), '"'),
                                                  j.value)),
                                       ','),
                               '}')
                 FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.employeeInfo') j
                 WHERE j.[key] IN ('age', 'gender', 'active')) + ', ' +

                (SELECT '"product":' + JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.product')) + '}'
```